# Alignment issue in 'Your Sites' section in the Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, android-app

There is some unwanted extra spaces in between each site in the **Your Sites** section.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Touch the **Nav Icon** in the left top corner
2. Touch the **EDIT** link in **YOUR SITES**
3. Scroll the screen; there is unwanted spaces in between the each site

For reference I recorded the same:

[image: Wired spacing in Your Sites]

Configurations:

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: Motorola
- Device Model: XT1033
- OS Version: 5.1 (2)

Comment: It's happening to me too, on my Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android 4.1.2. I'm just letting you know in case there's a question about device-specificity.

Comment: @Sue Thanks for sharing. Yeah, hope it is not the device specific problem.

Comment: I'm seeing this as well on my Droid Turbo 2 with Android 6.0.

Answer (score 1):

As of v1.0.94 <sup>or before, but after 1.0.89</sup>, it has been fixed.

[image: normal height again!]